# Multiple updates at once Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, insert, pymongo

I use bucket pattern for timeseries data.I use this code for importing my data into my table :

```
for file in sorted_files:
    df = process_file(file)

    for row,item in df.iterrows():
        data_dict = item.to_dict()
        mycol1.update_one(
            {"nsamples": {"$lt": 288}},
            {
                "$push": {"samples": data_dict},

                "$inc": {"nsamples": 1}
            },
            upsert=True
        )
```

The problem is that the insert is very very slow.Is there any way to get things done faster?Is there a way to do this with bulk insert?Is it possbile to do multiple updates ta once instead of one?Insert time is critical for me.Any advice would be appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is a [bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) option, but i am not sure its faster or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust your code to cut down the number of updates by quite a lot, right now let's say a bucket has `nsamples: 50` you execute 238 updates instead of a single update and a signle `insertMany` action.

Here's how I would approach this:

```
for file in sorted_files:
    df = process_file(file)

    row_count = df.shape[0]
    next_bucket = mycol1.find_one({"nsamples": {"$lt": 288}})

    if next_bucket:
        available_in_next_bucket = 288 - len(next_bucket['samples'])
        rows_for_update = df.iloc[0: available_in_next_bucket]
        mycol1.update_one(
            {_id: next_bucket['_id']},
            {
                "$push": {"samples": {"$each": rows_for_update}},
                "$inc": {"nsamples": len(rows_for_update)}
            })
    else:
        # if bucket doesn't exist can just skip to the next loop.
        available_in_next_bucket = 0

    # get the number of updates required past the initial bucket
    update_count = math.ceil((row_count - available_in_next_bucket) / 288)
    if update_count < 1:
        continue

    new_docs = []
    for i in range(update_count):
        # get rows for the next bucket
        rows_for_update = df.iloc[i * 288 + rows_for_update: ((i + 1) * 288) + rows_for_update]
        new_docs.append({
            "samples": rows_for_update,
            "nsamples": len(rows_for_update)
        })
    mycol1.insertMany(new_docs)
```

Now the strategy is to first update the last bucket. then iterate over the remaining rows in the `df` and split them accordingly, finally use a single `insertMany` operation to save the results

A few things to note:

- This code only works under the assumption there is at most 1 ( the last ) bucket with less than 288 samples, if this is not the case you can still keep the same "logic" of reducing the update calls but you'll have to adjust it to use updates instead of a single insertMany operation
- You could improve performance by moving the insert to outside the outer loop, I choose to leave it within it for readability purposes.
- One more caveat, I'm not a python wizard and I didn't debug this code, hence I expect some syntax errors to arise. However I do stand behind the approach of cutting down the number of calls to the db as that's the biggest overhead we can adjust to.

Comment: Thank you for your time!i appreciate it a lot!i will test the code and i and i will let you know if i need something else!

Comment: Note that my table is empty before the insertion..is this a problem?

Comment: Just change the update condition to support an empty query of the bucket doesn't exist

Comment: I've updated the snippet to reflect that,

Comment: Thank you tom!One last thing i dont understand..next_bucket=mycol1.find_one({"nsamples:{"$lt":288}}) gives me an error..i dont understand what are you doing there..can you help me a bit?i know i am asking much but i am drowning with this code :p

Comment: Also i cant fix the error here rows_for_update = df.iloc[i * 288 + rows_for_update: ((i + 1) * 288) + rows_for_update] it says that the second rows_for_update is undefinded

Comment: the find_one is just fetching the existing bucket so we can count how many "empty" slots it has, i'm not sure why and what error is occurring but i'm assuming it's python's dic syntax. so you'll need to define it else. that `iloc` fetching rows from a df in a range, again as i said i'm not an expert but it technically needs to be in the range of 0: df len -1. so maybe if it's bigger than df len -1 it throws an error. in that case you need to add max( (i + 1) * 288 + rows, df.shape[0])